# How to pass variable to a web services in c#?

Tags: web-services, rest, c#-4.0, drupal-7

I am calling a drupal web services from C#. My web service in drupal accepts two parameters. When i am checking my Web service with chrome extension POSTMAN. ITs working fine and returning me the data. But I have no idea how to pass those two values in web service. I have written my code like this

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://careernet.localhost/rep-details/report_details/retrieve");
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";
                    request.Accept = "application/xml";
                    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();                    
                    request.CookieContainer.Add(new Uri("http://careernet.localhost/rep-details/report_details/retrieve"), new Cookie("sid", sessid));
 WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

                        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The above code is works well if I don't have to pass any value and calling web service which does not accept any thing. But if I have to pass two values then how can I do it ?

Answer (score 0):

quick google search for "httpwebrequest post" and first result is:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

REST web services are nothing more than HTTP requests. When you want to send something using HTTP you send bytes which are not related with actual datatypes. This is why people very often use the [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/) objects to describe arguments and results when using web services.

[This post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes how you could make a POST HTTP request. In the step 7 you append some bytes in the request stream. This is where you should append your arguments.

If you see the full example (scroll down) you will see that the byte array appended to the stream is created using the following code snippet.

```
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "This is a test that posts this string to a Web server.";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (postData);
```

Since you only want to pass simple arguments and not objects, this would be sufficient. If you need to pass objects as arguments, I would suggest using JSON in the `postData`
string.

Hope I helped!